# Loading pandas data frame from pickle file in S3 bucket to AWS Lambda - problem with type

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mlops

I created a machine-learning model with a KNN classifier. Then, I made a pickle file of the test dataset and uploaded it to the AWS S3 bucket using AWS SDK.

For testing purposes, I have downloaded it and tested the type with the following:

```
with open("C:\\...path...\\test_features.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    test_data= pickle.load(f)
print(type(test_data))
```

The result is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`, which is ok.

However, when reading through AWS Lambda, the following part

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
test_features = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key= key)
print(type(test_features))
```

gives `<class 'dict'>`

How to get DataFrame type in AWS Lambda too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read content first then use pickle to load the content and create data frame

```
test_features = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key= key)
body = test_features['Body'].read()
test_data = pickle.loads(body)
print(type(test_data))
```

Comment: I get the error: 'errorMessage': "name 'response' is not defined"

Comment: There was a typo in the code change the response to test_features